# Scanning C header files and save the prototypes and variables in an ArrayList

Tags: java, c, header

I am making a simple c IDE through java. To set up auto completion feature I need to get the function prototypes of the included header file.

To start with I have scanned the header file out of the source code:

```
 ArrayList prototypes=new ArrayList();
String[] lines=source.split("\n");
for (String s: lines){
if(s.startsWith("#include"){
      String file="/usr/include/"+s.substring(s.indexOf("<")+1,s.indexOf(">")-1);
      //todo scanning the file
 }
}
```

So what code should replace the commented line so that I get all function prototypes in the header stored in the prototypes arraylist .

If any alternative is there such as an API that does the job feel free to suggest.

Comment: Your first question is too broad - parsing C is a non-trivial exercise (to say the least). Your second is off-topic, we don't do software/library recommendations here. Search for C parsers in Java, you might find a few.

Comment: I just want a simple method to get the function prototypes out of the header files. I don't want to do anything else. Is there any easy way or am I just going the wrong direction. And the search engine recommended c parsers are not suitable for this job they are all way to complex and in turn I will be requiring to reparse the parsers reply to get the job done.

Comment: Just open `/usr/include/stdio.h` for example. It's going to be really obvious that there is no "simple" way to parse this.

Comment: but I mean that can't the file be set in a for loop to parse the line one by one and report the lines that return ( and ). As only function prototypes has those which encloses a parameter. Or something in similar manner?

Comment: Did you actually look at the file? Do you see all those defines, prototypes on several lines, several versions of prototypes, compiler attributes, function pointers as arguments, etc? If you just want to do a quick "take each line that sort of looks like a prototype", just go ahead and do that, but your results will be terrible.

Comment: Don't forget to deal with `#define`.  It could make something that looks like a function prototype into something that isn't, or vice versa.

Comment: That is the reason I am asking for help

Comment: @aniruddha.sarkar When you want to write a good IDE, you won't get around implementing a feature-complete C lexer and parser which is the first part of a C compiler.